# Roots of the complex function

Tags: complex-numbers

How do i find the roots of the equation

$$ z^4-3iz^2 - 2 = 0 $$

I got $$ z^2 = 1 $$ $$z^2 = 2i $$ $$ \theta = 90 $$

Note:

I'm trying to solve using

$$ r^{1/n} exp[i( \frac{\phi}{n}) + (\frac{2 \pi k} {n})] $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you shall solve it in a very straightforward way.

Set

$$z^2 = x$$

and solve for $x$

$$x^2 - 3ix - 2 = 0$$

As a second degree complex equation.

$$x = \frac{3i\pm\sqrt{(3i)^2 +8}}{2}$$

$$x = \frac{3i\pm \sqrt{-9+8}}{2}$$

$$x = \frac{3i\pm\sqrt{-1}}{2}$$

$$x = \frac{3i\pm i}{2}$$

$$x_1 = 2i ~~~~~~~~~~~ x_2 = i$$

Now comeback to $z$.

$$z_1 = \sqrt{2i} ~~~~~~~~~~~ z_2 = \sqrt{i}$$

Comment: But how do I solve using the polar form and the formula in the question. Edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @vmark99 The formula you added is de Moivre's formula.  I applied it in my answer, though this was after I solved for $z^2$ with the quadratic formula.

Comment: Oh yea okay. So the other two roots are negatives of z1 and z2 right ?

Answer (score 0):

Write $w$ instead of $z^2$ to get
$$w^2-3iw-2=0$$

Then, you can use the formula $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. It works although there are non real coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.  I'd try a quadratic equation in $z^2$ to get:

$$z^2 = \frac{3i \pm \sqrt{-9 + 8}}{2} = i, 2i$$

From there, I'd probably express these solutions in polar form:  $e^{i\pi/2}, 2e^{i\pi/2}$, and use de Moivre's formula to get the solutions for $z$:

$$e^{i\pi/4}, e^{5i\pi/4}, \sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}, \sqrt{2}e^{5i\pi/4}.$$

These in Cartesian form are:

$$\frac{\pm(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}, \pm(1+i).$$

Comment: But how do I solve using the polar form and the formula in the question. Edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: That expression gives the $n$th roots for $re^{i\theta}$.  Your equation isn't in that form. If you solve for $z^2$ like I did using the quadratic formula, then it *is* in that form, and you can use it (with $n=2$).

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you first substitute $z^2$ with $w$ and solve $w^2-3iw-2=0$ to get $w=i,2i$ and so $w=z^2=i$ or $2i$.
The formula you posted is used to find the n-th root of a complex number, meaning to find $z$ when $z^n=w$. In this case need to find the square root of $i$ and $2i$ so $n=2$.

So, using that formula:

r will be the length of $w$, in this case $|2i|=2,|i|=1$
$\phi = argw$ , so for both $w=2i$ and $w=i$: $\phi=\pi/2+2\pi k$

So for $w=2i$ the formula gives $z=\sqrt 2 e^{{2k\pi + \pi/2}\over {2}}$
and for $w=i$, $z=e^{{2k\pi + \pi/2}\over {2}}$